# Connection between OpenCV and OpenGL in Java with Tetris Game

Tags: java, opencv, opengl

I have a Tetris project that needs to work with Camera. That is, there are two windows. One loads webcam (OpenCV) and is detected red triangle or square. Other window is the Tetris game(OpenGL) that each tile will come down one by one from top to bottom.
All functions are already written and everything works. Now I need to connect the two.
I write here part code of classes
In the class BoxLightTextRendererPP you can see the positioning of the game piece.
In the VideoProcessing class you can see the contour detection by the camera.
and in the InteractionHandler class I have to write a method, where e.g. with Switch-Case it is detected, if the camera sees a square, then move the token to the left and if a triangle is detected move it to the right.
How can I do this?

BoxLightTexRendererPP:

```
// Pointers (names) for data transfer and handling on GPU
private int[] vaoName;  // Name of vertex array object
private int[] vboName;  // Name of vertex buffer object
private int[] iboName;  // Name of index buffer object

float[] barrey = verticies;
int block = 28;
//Startpunkt rechts/links
static float x = -1.5f;
//Startpunkt oben/unten
float h = 1.5f;
//Startpunkt vorne/hinten
float y = 0;
//Fallgeschwindigkeit
float fall = 0.01f;
boolean start = true;
public static boolean go = false;
boolean stay = false;
float[] barrey1 = verticies;
int block1 = 28;
```

VideoProcessing:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                MatOfPoint2f approx = new MatOfPoint2f(); //approx parameter count contours of objects; important for interaction handling
                //allows the approximation of polygons and determine scope of object
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(newContours.get(idx), approx, Imgproc.arcLength(newContours.get(idx), true) * 0.02, true);
                long count = approx.total();
                //filtering small blobs
                if(Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(idx))) > 1000) {

                    //draw contours on objects
                    if (count == 5) {
                        Imgproc.drawContours(frame, contours, idx, new Scalar(75, 0, 0));
                    }
                    if (count == 6) {
                        Imgproc.drawContours(frame, contours, idx, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
                    }
                    if (count == 4) {
                        Imgproc.drawContours(frame, contours, idx, new Scalar(200, 0, 0));
                        viereck = (int) count;
                    }
                    if (count == 3) {
                        Imgproc.drawContours(frame, contours, idx, new Scalar(360, 100, 50));
                        dreieck = (int) count;
                    }
                }
            }
```

InteractionHandler:

```
public void connection() {
        float xAchse = BoxLightTexRendererPP.x;
        int viereck = VideoProcessing.viereck;
        int dreieck = VideoProcessing.dreieck;
        

        Switch(xAchse)
??????????????


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer: InteractionHandler is not important.
Just modified Video Processing:
(There is still a collision detection problem. I am still working on that.)

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                MatOfPoint2f approx = new MatOfPoint2f(); //approx parameter count contours of objects; important for interaction handling
                //allows the approximation of polygons and determine scope of object
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(newContours.get(idx), approx, Imgproc.arcLength(newContours.get(idx), true) * 0.02, true);
                long count = approx.total();
                //filtering small blobs
                if(Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(idx))) > 1000) {

                    //draw contours on objects
                    if (count == 5) {
                        Imgproc.drawContours(frame, contours, idx, new Scalar(75, 0, 0));
                        BoxLightTexMainWindowPP.errorLog.setText("Fünfeck erkannt");
                        BoxLightTexRendererPP.x -= 0.1;
                    }
                    if (count == 6) {
                        Imgproc.drawContours(frame, contours, idx, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
                        BoxLightTexMainWindowPP.errorLog.setText("Sechseck erkannt");
                        BoxLightTexRendererPP.y -= 0.1;
                    }
                    if (count == 4) {
                        Imgproc.drawContours(frame, contours, idx, new Scalar(200, 0, 0));
                        BoxLightTexMainWindowPP.errorLog.setText("Viereck erkannt");
                        BoxLightTexRendererPP.x += 0.1;
                    }
                    if (count == 3) {
                        Imgproc.drawContours(frame, contours, idx, new Scalar(360, 100, 50));
                        BoxLightTexMainWindowPP.errorLog.setText("Dreieck erkannt");
                        BoxLightTexRendererPP.y += 0.1;
                    }
                }
            }
```